# How do I use a button to change background color when pressed once and when pressed again it should retain to original color in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, button

So I was trying to make a interactive button, when pressed on the button, the background color of the button should change to dark green and if user presses it again, it should get deactivated and change back to light green background.

[Light Green Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtX3O.png)   ->  [Dark Green Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwejX.png)
and when pressed again
[Dark Green Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwejX.png)   ->  [Light Green Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtX3O.png)

How can I do this using JavaScript and HTML?

Comment: toggle a class.....

Comment: Give it a try first. Please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Let us know [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) and what didn't work. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Also search. It's probably been asked and answered.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and put it in the question itself instead.